vue vitest method is being called, but spy is not
I am trying to assert that the method util.download() of my useUtils() composable gets called. The console.logs shows that the method was indeed called, but the test fails: expected "download" to be called at least once. Here is the console.log outputs:
spy created
calling store.download
util.download called
Repository.postDownload triggered

I am unsure if there is a race condition, as I have called flushPromises() before the assertion. Code snippets:
test_spec.js:
describe('my test', () => {
    test('util.download is called', async () => {
        Repository.postDownload.mockImplementationOnce(async () => {
            const data = {foo:'bar'}
            console.log('Repository.postDownload triggered')
            return Promise.resolve(data)
        })
        const store = useMyStore()
        const util = useUtility()
        const utilSpy = vi.spyOn(util, 'download')
        console.log('spy created')
        await store.download()
        await flushPromises()
        expect(utilSpy).toHaveBeenCalledOnce()
    })
})

myStore.js
export const useMyStore = defineStore('MyStore', () => {
  const util = useUtility()
  const download async = () => {
    // ...
    console.log("calling store.download")
    await util.download(params)
}


util.js
export const useUtility = () => {
  const download = async (params) => {
    console.log("util.download called")
    // ...
    const res = await repository.postDownload()
    // ...
}


You omitted the relevant part in myStore.js. There's const util = useUtility() in "...", isn't it? You can't mock or spy on it because useUtility().download != useUtility().download

Yes, I have missed that part. I have now added it to the question. How should I mock the util instance that was created and called in the store, in this case?

You need to either mock the whole useUtility, or a part of it that creates undesirable side effects (repository)
